# Hokkien name to Mandarin

Tags: meaning, mandarin, names, hokkien

A friend of mine has a Hokkien name of 'eng leng' (leng is long and means dragon). However, I have no idea of this 'eng'. This name was given by her ancestor who is really passed. So I am helpless trying to find out this name.

I tried finding 'eng', but I don't know the real tone and 'eng' has many different meanings. Which 'eng' should it be as a part of female name?

Comment: Try 榮龍 \(êng lêng, [Hokkien POJ Romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe%CC%8Dh-%C5%8De-j%C4%AB)\). In general, this is not a solvable question, you need to give the meaning of "eng" or at least tell us whether it is the family name or generation name.

Comment: Family name is lín 林

Comment: The meaning of eng is i really dont know so i have to ask. If i know i can just write this.

Comment: I really wanna know whether someone heard one named the same or if someone know the compatible or suitable word with dragon in different meanings of this eng. I am just beginner lvl learner of chinese so i dunno too much and thats why.

Comment: In hokkien, her full name is lin eng leng.

Comment: Can u explain the meaning of 荣龙 as a name and whether is it possible as a female name or not?? Plz

Answer (score 1):

Quote:- "Which should it be as a part of female name???"

I don't know about mainland Hokkien, but in S-E Asia, "Eng", (in Hokkien, sounding like "Eng" of England with a neutral tone), usually stands for 英. Coincidentally, also as in 英国

And even more coincidentally，my wife who is Hokkien also has "Eng", 英 in her name :)

Comment: If u dont mind may i know first name of ur wife?

Comment: The 英, ("eng") in my wife's name appears in her personal name and not as first name or surname. Her surname is 颜 (Yán in Mandarin) and "Gan", (pronounced like "gun" in Hokkien) As you know, in Chinese names, the surname comes first, so, her full Chinese name is 颜 美 英, (in Hokkien -- Gan Bee Eng) Hope you and your friend find this discussion useful, though of course some uncertainty still remains. My answer is based on what S-E Asian Hokkiens normally use.

Comment: I m confusing between 英 or 荣. However thanks u for ur idea

Comment: Ur discussion is really useful. I appreciate it.

Comment: In your wife name, yīng may be flower but if it is combined with lóng it means brave so i think it is not possible for female name. I m confused with chinese. It is so complex.

Comment: Well, for a start it is really uncommon / unusual, (whether in Hokkien or other communities or indeed any racial group) to have 龙, (dragon) as part of a girl's name, unless she is born in the year of a Dragon, and even so no parents would name their daughters with such powerful, masculine, imperious connotations. Not to say of course that your friend is "badly" named as her parents may have good reasons, for example she was born under some "weak" astrological sign and so the powerful 英龙 is meant to give her "energy" to fight on and overcome all obstacles?

Comment: Oh i see! Thanks for ur explanation

Answer (score 1):

the internet archive has two hokkkien chinese-english dictionary:

[A dictionary of the Hok-këèn dialect of the Chinese language](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryofhokk00medhrich/)

[Chinese-English dictionary of the vernacular or spoken language of Amoy](https://archive.org/details/chineseenglishdi00doug/)

that, “eng” could be 英, 鶯, 應, 永, 影, 榮, 瑩, 盈, 詠, . . .

p174-179 of the 1st, p45-46 of the 2nd

and “leng” could be 令, 羚, 寧, 靈, 能, 龍, . . .

p448-451 of the 1st, p141-142 of the 2nd

the combination of “eng-leng” is a large grid, even for female name.

so, may i ask, why & how do you know that “leng” is “龍”?

Comment: She is born in dragon zodiac and she is sure for this character because it is easy to remember a zodiac creature on her name. May be she knew the whole meaning of her name in the past but now she forget. Even she has forgot, the zodiac dragon is only one she still remembers. The reason is because of her zodiac sign.

Comment: If last one is dragon, may i know which is most compatible or suitable for this one. I really want your opinion.

Comment: If assume the later one isnt dragon, which combination of the two characters is most suitable as a female name?

Comment: i see, then in sequence, i would choose 英龍, 應龍, 永龍 or 詠龍. the meaning of the first character would be find in dictionary mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your effort, brother. I will definitely try them!